# Чи правильно ми перекладаємо "string matching"

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Найчастіше я чув як *пошук підрядка*. Тут мені незрозуміло,

1. чому *під-* адже *string*, а не *substring*. А також matching, то не дуже вже й пошук.
2. Також є *pattern matching*, для якого *string matching* є частковим випадком, і який перекладається як *зіставляння із взірцем*. [[1]](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=matching&dicts=all&highlight=on)

З іншого боку *пошук підрядка* вже інтуїтивно зрозуміло, тоді як *зіставляння із рядком* потребує певного часу для входження в мову.

> Ми формалізуємо задачу зіставляння із рядком так.
>   Припустимо, що текст -- це масив ***T***[1:n] завдовжки *n* і, що взірець
>   це масив ***P***[1:m] завдовжки *m*, де *m <= n*. Також припускаємо,
>   що елементи з ***P*** and ***T*** -- це символи зі скінченної абетки Ʃ.
>   Наприклад, Ʃ = {0,1} або Ʃ = {а, б, ..., я}. Масиви
>   символів P і T часто називають **рядками** символів.

От знайшов такий варіант:

[ПОШУК ЗРАЗКА В РЯДКУ](http://www.unicyb.kiev.ua/Library/PROG/abutt2.htm) А.Б.Ставровський *Посібник з програмування для студентів 1 курсу факультету кібернетики*

Comment: Також чув *«співставлення»*, але скупчення приголосних реально жахливе.

Comment: Краще тоді вже не співставлення а зіставлення http://sum.in.ua/s/zistavlennja

Comment: сватання стрічок :)

Comment: Microsoft: [зіставлення рядка](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=string+matching&langID=uk-ua).

Comment: Але є й [substring search](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/53SubstringSearch.pdf) — що очевидно перекладається як «пошук підрядка» ([1](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=find+substring&langID=uk-ua), [2](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=find+the+substring&langID=uk-ua), [3](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=substring+to+search&langID=uk-ua)).

Comment: @Sasha Ага, зрозуміло звідки взявся "пошук підрядку". І дякую за Vicrosoft словник, не знав про нього. Можливо ці ваші два коменти оформити як відповідь?

Answer (score 1):

Якщо звернемося до англійської [Вікіпедії](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), то знайдемо там статтю про "string matching algorithms" (або ж "string searching algorithms", бо обидва терміни мають одне і теж значення). На тій же [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) обираємо українську мову і отримуємо варіант "Алгоритм пошуку рядка".

Можна зробити висновок, що у даному контексті (мова іде про інформатику та комп'ютерні технології) "string matching" можна перекласти як "пошук рядка"

"Substring" перекладається як "[підрядок](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/substring)", тоді й сам термін можна перекласти як "пошук підрядка" (щоб переконати у правильності перекладу слова "підрядок" також наведу речення із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA): "У деяких мовах (наприклад, Standard ML) крім цього, є додатковий модуль для забезпечення ще більшої ефективності — «підрядок» (SubString)"). Крім того в інформатиції існує таке поняття як "[прямий пошук підрядка у рядку](http://choippo.cn.sch.in.ua/Files/downloadcenter/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8.pdf)".

Comment: на цьому сайті вікіпедію не вважають надто надійним джерелом. можна запитати, чому ви не скористались, наприклад, цими словниками замість вікіпедії: e2u.org.ua?